# Get id of Table row with specific class Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the id value of each row in my table that has the class selected. I need to be able to do this in javascript; not jquery.

```
<tr id="1" class="selected"></tr>
<tr id="2"></tr>
<tr id="3" class="selected"></tr>
<tr id="4"></tr>
```

This should return an array: `[1,3]`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, show your try first!

Comment: If you want to use javascript only, why tag with jQuery?

Comment: look something like `selector`

Comment: `var ids = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.selected')).map(function (x) { return x.id; });`

Comment: @adeneo: That's an answer, dude. But no need for the `slice`: `var ids = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.selected'), function(element) { return element.id; });`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and something very similar to what I've typed in ready to hit the button once op shows his efforts :p

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - giving someone else a chance! This shouldn't be to hard with a loop either, and the OP should at least show some effort.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `slice` is needed or else, we need to use call on map as it's `NodeList` and not actual array.

Comment: @AmitJoki: Right, as I showed. Much more efficient. No need for a temp array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - ah, yes, passing it directly to map works to, didn't think of that, I was just focused on getting an array to map

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah! Didn't saw it. Now that's what I had typed in :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution, using PureJS. no Jquery at all.

used getElementsByClassName.

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
var array = cont.getElementsByClassName("selected");

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)alert(array[i].id);
```

```html
<table id="container">
<tr id="1" class="selected">asdasd</tr>
<tr id="2">asdasdasd</tr>
<tr id="3" class="selected">asdasdasd</tr>
<tr id="4">asdasdasd</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
var idArray=[];
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    idArray.push(elements[i].attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the elements, convert to array, extract the ids. Simple:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
var elements_array = [].slice.call(elements);
var ids = elements_array .map(function(element){ return element.id });
```

Even easier in jQuery though:

```
var ids = $(".selected").map(function(index, element){return element.id});
```

Comment: "Even easier" Because it is one line?

Comment: One line, and no array conversion. I'll admit that easier is just my opinion though.

Comment: Only 1000s of lines of jQuery make it easier. LOL,  I can hide the code in a function and it will look even easier. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected elements using `querySelectorAll`:

```
var selected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
```

...then you can get their `id`s by applying `Array#map` even though `selected` is a `NodeList` rather than an array:

```
var ids = Array.prototype.map.call(selected, function(element) {
    return element.id;
});
```

All in one:

```
var ids = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".selected"), function(element) {
    return element.id;
});
```

---

`querySelectorAll` is supported by all modern browsers, and also by IE8.

`Array.prototype.map` exists on all modern browsers, and can be easily polyfilled on older ones like IE8.

---

If you're going to do this a lot, it's handy to grab a copy of `map` to a variable:

```
var map = Array.prototype.map;

// ...later...

var ids = map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".selected"), function(element) {
    return element.id;
});
```